# Regex to see if last character is 'U' or 'C'

Tags: regex, acrobat

I am writing an Acrobat Professional DC custom Preflight profile in which I need to check if the spot colors names finishes with either 'U' or 'C'.

Can a regex solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This regex does that:

```
[UC]$
```

The `$` ensures that the match occurs at the end of the string.

Comment: Didn't know it could be that simple. What an elegant solution. If you know a good place to learn more about regex, let me know!

Answer (score -1):

The regex that would match that (under posix) would be something like this:

`^([:alnum:]|[:punct:])*(U|C)$`

explanation:

`^` means the start of the string.

`[:alnum:]` This is the class of all alphanumeric characters

`[:punct:]` The class of all punctuation characters (eg "!" or ".", etc.  I'm not sure what format you have)

`|` means "or"

`*` Means 0 or more occurrences of the preceding atom.

`()` makes the regular expression inside an atom.

`$` is like `^`, but it means the end of the string.

This will match any lines beginning with any combination of alphanumeric characters and punctuation (including 0 of each) and ending with either 'U' or 'C'.

Comment: Never use alternation when you can use a character class. Alternation is slower. Why is the first part of the regex is necessary?